# OWIN-Getting dbo.AspNetUser Id in Web API controller. User.Identity.GetUserId() is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get reference to the ID the Identity framework assigns my users so I can make that a foreign key in my sql db, it is currently coming back as null:
[image]

My Startup.cs:

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultAPI",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config); 
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider:

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider 
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        //context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

AuthRespository.cs:

```
 public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
{
    private AuthContext _ctx;
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public AuthRepository()
    {
        _ctx = new AuthContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = userModel.UserName
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        return user;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctx.Dispose();
        _userManager.Dispose();

    }
}
```

UserModel.cs:

```
 public class UserModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

When the control flow gets into GrantResourceOwnerCredentials context.UserName is properly set but the context.ClientId is null. How can I get this piece of information?

Edit:

I see that in the lines of code:

```
 using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }
```

user.Id is the exact Id I am looking for. But I am not allowed to assign it to context.ClientId. Any ideas?

Comment: Is client_id is present in your request?

Comment: Check the edit i made at the bottom, it was not in the context

Comment: See this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthgrantresourceownercredentialscontext.clientid(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.ClientId

You cannot pass value in ClientId inside GrantResourceOwnerCredentials as it is private set.

If you want to have value in your ClientId, It should be present in your request

Answer (score 0):

Got around this by taking the User.Id property and manually setting this to a SID Claim in my Identity. It isn't perfect but it is the same ID anyway.